# PySpark's reduceByKey not working as expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce

I'm writing a large PySpark program and I've recently run into trouble when using `reduceByKey` on an RDD. I've been able to recreate the problem with a simple test program. The code is:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

APP_NAME = 'Test App'

def main(sc):
    test = [(0, [i]) for i in xrange(100)]
    test = sc.parallelize(test)
    test = test.reduceByKey(method)
    print test.collect()

def method(x, y):
    x.append(y[0])
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure Spark
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
    conf = conf.setMaster('local[*]')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    main(sc)
```

I would expect the output to be `(0, [0,1,2,3,4,...,98,99])` based on the Spark documentation. Instead, I get the following output:

```
[(0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84])]
```

Could someone please help me understand why this output is being generated?

As a side note, when I use

```
def method(x, y):
    x = x + y
    return x
```

I get the expected output.

Comment: As a small note, if you do decide to stick with using `reduceByKey` (vs `groupByKey`), there is an action called `reduce(_func_)` that functions as a reduce and then collect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it looks like you actually want `groupByKey` not `reduceByKey`:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(0, i) for i in xrange(100)])
grouped = rdd.groupByKey()
k, vs = grouped.first()
assert len(list(vs)) == 100
```

> Could someone please help me understand why this output is being generated?

`reduceByKey` [assumes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.reduceByKey) that `f` is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) and your `method` is clearly not. Depending on the order of operations the output is different. Lets say you start with following data for a certain key:

```
[1], [2], [3], [4]
```

Now add lets add some parentheses:

1. `((([1], [2]), [3]), [4])`
2. `(([1, 2], [3]), [4])`
3. `([1, 2, 3], [4])`
4. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

and with another set of parentheses

1. `(([1], ([2], [3])), [4])`
2. `(([1], [2, 3]), [4])`
3. `([1, 2], [4])`
4. `[1, 2, 4]`

When you rewrite it as follows:

```
method = lambda x, y: x + y
```

or simply

```
from operator import add
method = add
```

you get an associative function and it works as expected.

Generally speaking for `reduce*` operations you want functions which are both associative and [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).